# How can I fix this CSS positioning for the transition to work? (CSS3 with Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate the effect seen on the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7studio/wQQCP/

Basically it's a horizontal list with a line marker that moves around as the mouse hover over items.

Here's my attempt to replicate it: http://jsfiddle.net/yt24oj2w/

On a new page (with Bootstrap layout), I created a similar list:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Options</h3>
            <hr/>
            <div class="options">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                    <li class="n1"><a href="#">Items</a></li>
                    <li class="n2"><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
                    <li class="n3 selected"><a href="#">Oldest</a></li>
                    <li class="quebec">&nbsp;</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is exactly the same as the original:

```
a { color: #7c7c7c; }
a:hover, a:focus { text-decoration: none; }
ul { position: relative; overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; }

li {
    list-style: none outside;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ececec;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}
li a {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.n1 { width: 110px; }
.n2 { width: 110px; }
.n3 {
    width: 110px;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.selected a {
    border-bottom-color: #cfd0d0;
    color: #340e56;
}

.quebec {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background: #511d7f;

    -webkit-transition-property: left, width;
    -moz-transition-property: left, width;
    -ms-transition-property: left, width;
    -o-transition-property: left, width;
    transition-property: left, width;

    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
    -o-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;

    pointer-events: none;
}

li:hover {
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.n1:hover ~ li.quebec { left: 0; width: 110px; }
.n2:hover ~ li.quebec { left: 130px; width: 110px; }
.n3:hover ~ li.quebec { left: 260px; width: 110px; }
```

However, when hovering the list, you can see that the list items change position to the left.

I do understand that I'm not using the correct widths and left values for the hover classes but that's just for testing.

What's confusing me is that the items (or the links inside them) are changing position when hovering. I already tried creating this sample from scratch without any luck.

I appreciate any help figuring that out, since I'm using exactly the same CSS. The only difference would be the Bootstrap classes.

Also, as I pointed just above, I couldn't figure out whether is the **li** or the **a** changing position. I appreciate if you can tell me how to figure that one out aswell for future reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your `li:hover` thats causing the issue and also some of the bootstrap css you need to add some css to undo the changes that bootstrap makes.

change these around:

```
.n3 {
width: 110px;
padding-right: 0 !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
}

li:hover {
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For future checking of your code, using chrome or firefox you can right click on the page and select inspect element then use this to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like magic. I've been testing with IE11. But at least on my machine it doesn't show DOM changes without closing and opening again the developer tools. I'm going Chrome/Firefox from here on now.